# Proposition 3.23 of Logic for Mathematicians by A.G. Hamiltom? Just case 3.

Tags: first-order-logic

I am trying to understand the proposition 3.23 of Logic for Mathematicians by A.G. Hamiltom. But I am confused by the proof of case 3.
Please help me.

> Let $\mathscr A(x_i)$ be a wf. of $\mathscr L$ in which $x_i$ appears free, and let $t$ be a term which is free for $x_i$ in $\mathscr A(x_i)$. Suppose that $v$ is a valuation and $v'$ is the valuation which is $i$-equivalent to $v$ and has $v'(x_i)=v(t)$. Then $v$ satisfies $\mathscr A(t)$ if and only if $v'$ satisfies $\mathscr A(x_i)$

First, Hamilton gives a Preliminary result which says：
For any term $u$ in which $x_i$ occurs we can obtain a term $u'$ by substituting $t$ for $x_i$ throughout, and that then $v(u' )=v' (u)$.

Next, Hamilton proves the proposition by induction on the number of connectives and quantifiers.

Base step: atomic formulas.

Induction step:

Case 1. $\mathscr A(x_i)$ is $\lnot \mathscr B(x_i )$. …

Case 2. $\mathscr A(x_i )$ is $(\mathscr B(x_i) → \mathscr C(x_i ))$. …

Case 3. $\mathscr A(x_i )$ is $(∀x_j )\mathscr B(x_i )$. …

In case 3, even though it is not easy to understand why “$v(t)=w(t)$”, but I tried accepting this by intuitive, and learned that

$v$ satisfies $\mathscr A(t)$  implies $v'$  satisfies $\mathscr A(x_i )$

However, I can not get the conclusion that

$v'$  satisfies $\mathscr A(x_i )$  implies $v$ satisfies $\mathscr A(t)$.

I guess that it may be proved by supposing for the sake of contradiction that “$v$ does satisfies $\mathscr A(t)$ and $v'$  satisfies $\mathscr A(x_i )$”.

Comment: what does it mean "that v is a valuation and v′ is the valuation which is i-equivalent to v and has $v′(x_i)=v(t)$"? It means that the two valuations (see page 60) agree on every "point" except (possibly) the $i$-th. But we have the extra-condition that $v'(x_i)$ has the same value that $v(t)$. Thus, when we replace free occurrences of $x_i$ by the new term $t$, the two valuations will behave exactly the same.

Comment: Do you understand the Preliminary lemma? We have a *term* $u$ with $x_i$ free (Example: $u$ is $x_i+0$) and we replace $x_i$ with $t$ getting a new term $u'$ (Example with $1$ as $t$ : $u'$ is $1+0$). If the valuation $v'$ maps $x_i$ to the same "object" that is $v(t)$ then the two valuations $v$ and $v'$ will map the two terms $u$ and $u'$ to the same object, i.e. $v(u')=v'(u)$. Example with $v'(x_i)= \text {the number one}$, because if term $t$ is $1$ then $v(t)= \text {the number one}$.

Comment: Obviously case 3 is the tricky one... we have two variables in play into formula $A(x_i) = (\forall x_j) B(x_i)$. We consider $v$ that **does not** sat $A(t)$ (that is: $A[t/x_i]$) and this means, by inductive def of sat (page 61), that some $j$-equiv $w$ (because we are removing the quantifier $(\forall x_j)$) **does not** sat $B(t)$. Now we consider $w'$ that is $i$-equiv to $w$; this means that $w'$ agree with $w$ everywhere except $x_i$ but we add the extra-condition that $w'(x_i)=w(t)$.

Comment: Now $w'$ is $i$-equiv to $w$ and $w$ does not sat $B(t)$: apply Induction hyp and conclude that $w'$ does not sat $B(x_i)$. Now a new tricky point: due to the condition $t$ *free for* $x_i$ in formula, we have to conclude that $x_i$ does not occur in $t$ at all. Thus, the "value" of $v(t)$ is **not** affected by what valuation $v$ assign to variable $x_i$; but from $v$ to $w$ we have changed only the value for $x_j$ and form $w$ to $w'$ we have changed only the value for $x_i$.

Comment: Now compute: $w(x_j) \ne v(x_j)$ meaning that on all other variables the two are the same. And $w'(x_i)=v(t)$ but for all other index except $i$ $w'$ is the same as $w$. Thus, $w'$ is the same as $v$ on all index except $j$ (by def of $w$) and and $i$ (because we have defined $w'(x_i)=v(t)$). But $x_j$ does not affect $t$ and so, due to the fact that $v(x_k)=w(x_k)$ for every $k \ne j$ we have that $w(t)=v(t)$

Comment: Do you see here the fact? $v(t)$ has a certain value and due to the fact that $x_j$ does not occur in $t$, whatever is the value that some other $j$-variant assign to $x_j$ the value for $t$ does not change. This the reason why $w(t)=v(t)$.

Comment: So again, $w'$ is a $i$-variant of $w$ and $w$ is a $j$-variant of $v$. But $w'(x_i)=v(t)$ and $v'$ is defined so that $v'(x_i)=v(t)$ and $v'$ is equal to $v$ for every other index. Thus, $w'$ and $v'$ are the same for $x_i$ and this means that $w'$ and $v'$ agree everywhere except $x_j$. The conclusion is: $w'$ is a $j$-variant of $v'$. Having found a $j$-variant of $v'$ that does not sat $B(x_i)$ we have to conclude that $v'$ does not sat $(\forall x_j)B(x_i)$ that is $A(x_i)$.